# How to serve Google Cloud Storage images?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I want `google.appengine.ext.blobstore` and `google.appengine.api.images` to work outside of App Engine. Do these modules require App Engine in order to work? I want to create public but not guessable URLs of my images on Google Cloud Storage and serve them via Django.

I read that this is done with `google.appengine.ext.blobstore.create_gs_key()` and `google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url()`. This is what I have so far:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

bucketname = 'mybucket'

gcs_object_name = '/gs/mybucket/vincent-van-gogh/the-starry-night.jpg'
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(gcs_object_name)
image_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
```

And image_url is supposed to be a public but not guessable URL of my image. If I run this code, the error is

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "blobstore"
```

This suggests blobstore needs a proxy, aka App Engine, in order to work its magic. Can App Engine modules work outside of App Engine? The docs say the above is a powerful way to serve images because I can generate a URL for each image and also resize the image dynamically.

Will this strategy work or is there a better way to serve images from Google Cloud Storage with Django?

Comment: That won't work. Prerequisites: "You need to have an appengine project. This will not work as a standalone solution for non appengine django projects, since there is no authentication mechanism with the google cloud storage implemented."

Comment: I don't have an App Engine project, and I don't want one. I have a standalone Django project on Google Compute Engine.

Comment: You can serve your images directly from the storage bucket, just make it world readable. You have to use App Engine to use App Engine components like blobstore, get_serving URL afaik.

Comment: You are correct. I'm looking into the Google APIs Client Library for Python now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blobstore and images APIs are available only within the App Engine runtime environment. To run them inside compute engine you can:

- Run them inside [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) (the GAE runtime environment on GCE)
- Run them on your own infrastructure or GCE using a GAE API emulator (such as [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/))
- Use public APIs (such as Google Cloud Storage) instead

Some App Engine services (such as [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs)) now also expose public APIs that you can use from GCE.