# How to get my image (base64) in Google-Cloud-Storage with go script

Tags: image, google-app-engine, go, base64, google-cloud-storage

I have been looking for an example GAE script in [**go**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286534/test-cases-for-go-and-appengine) to get my image that I got from the resulted screenshot of [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/first-app) and saved it as *json_decode* object using [Kohana/Cache](https://github.com/kohana/cache/tree/v3.3.0) to *Google Cloud Storage (GCS)*.

The reason of this method is simply because I found this Kohana model is the most convenient way writing files to GCS, although I am seeking also other way like [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987062/how-to-serve-google-cloud-storage-images) to write files to GCS using [*Blobstore*](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python) to serve them while the Go API Files has been deprecate as documented [*here*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/).

Here is the form of stored object containing the screenshot image data (base64) which is saved as public in default application bucket with object name [*images/thumb/mythumb.jpg*](https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/hyip-investment-monitors.appspot.com/o/images%2Fthumb%2Fmythumb.jpg):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [screenshot] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => _9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_...= // base64 data
            [height] => 240
            [mime_type] => image/jpeg
            [width] => 320
        )

    [otherdata] => Array
        (
            [..] => ..
            [..] => ..
        )

)
```

I want to get this image that set as [*public*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#permissions_caching_and_metadata_options) using my customized url as below that to be proceed through `go module` and also I need it to be expired in a certain time because I have managed to update the image content itself regularly:

> `http://myappId.appspot.com/image/thumb/mythumb.jpg`

I have set in *disptach.yaml* to send all image request to my `go module` as below:

```
- url: "*/images/*"
  module: go
```

and set the handler in *go.yaml* to proceed the image request as below:

```
handlers:
- url: /images/thumb/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

Using this directive I have got that all */images/* request (other than */images/thumb/* request) serve images from the static directory and that */images/thumb/mythumb.jpg* goes to the module application.

So left what code I have to use (see `????`) in my application file named *thumb.go* as below:

```
package thumb

import(
    //what to import
    ????
    ????
)

const (
    googleAccessID            = "<serviceAccountEmail>@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    serviceAccountPEMFilename = "YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.pem"
    bucket                    = "myappId.appspot.com"
)

var (
    expiration = time.Now().Add(time.Second * 60) //expire in 60 seconds
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/images/thumb/", handleThumb)
}

func handleThumb(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := cloud.NewContext(appengine.AppID(c), hc)
    ???? //what code to get the string of 'mythumb.jpg' from url
    ???? //what code to get the image stored data from GCS
    ???? //what code to encoce base64 data
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg;")    
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", mythumb.jpg)
}
```

I have taken many codes from some examples like [*this*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted), [*this*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#signing-code-go) or [*this*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples) but could not get one works so far. I have also tried a sample from [*this*](http://play.golang.org/p/TkKRROJTfb) which is almost close to [*my case*](http://play.golang.org/p/oS2K-Z4NQx) but also found no luck.

So in generally t was mainly due to lack on what are the correct code to be put on the line that I marked by `????` as well the relevant library or path to be imported. I have also checked the [*GCS permission*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/activate) if something have been missing as described [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294785/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-for-php) and [*here*](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/118).

I shall thank you much for your help and advise.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've read in your description, it seems that the only relevant parts are the `????` lines in the actual Go code. Let me know if that's not the case.

## First ????: "what code to get the string of 'mythumb.jpg' from url"?

From reading the code, you're looking to extract `mythumb.jpg` from a url like `http://localhost/images/thumb/mythumb.jpg`. A working example is available at the [Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_3) tutorial:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Such that

```
http://localhost:8080/monkeys
```

Prints

```
Hi there, I love monkeys!
```

## Second ????: "what code to get the image stored data from GCS"?

The API method you're probably looking to use is [storage.objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get).

You did link to one of the [JSON API Go Examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples) for Google Cloud Storage, which is a good general reference, but is not related to the problem you're trying to solve. That particular example is put together for Client-side applications (hence the `redirectURL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"` line). Additionally, this sample uses deprecated/out-of-date oauth2 and storage packages.

One of the cleanest (and non-deprecated) ways to do this for an application which wants to access its own buckets on behalf of itself would be to use the [golang/oauth2](https://github.com/golang/oauth2) and [Google APIs Client Library for Go](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client) packages.

An example of how to authenticate with JSON Web Token auth with the [golang/oauth2](https://github.com/golang/oauth2) package is [available in the repo](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/jwt/example_test.go):

```
func ExampleJWTConfig() {
    conf := &jwt.Config{
        Email: "xxx@developer.com",
        // The contents of your RSA private key or your PEM file
        // that contains a private key.
        // If you have a p12 file instead, you
        // can use `openssl` to export the private key into a pem file.
        //
        //    $ openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes
        //
        // It only supports PEM containers with no passphrase.
        PrivateKey: []byte("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----..."),
        Subject:    "user@example.com",
        TokenURL:   "https://provider.com/o/oauth2/token",
    }
    // Initiate an http.Client, the following GET request will be
    // authorized and authenticated on the behalf of user@example.com.
    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
    client.Get("...")
}
```

Next, instead of using the oauth2 `client` directly, use that client with the [Google APIs Client Library for Go](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client) mentioned earlier:

```
service, err := storage.New(client)
if err != nil {
    fatalf(service, "Failed to create service %v", err)
}
```

Notice the similarity to the out-of-date [JSON API Go Examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples)?

In your handler, you'll want to go out and get the related object using [`func ObjectsService.Get`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1#ObjectsService.Get). Assuming that you know the name of the `object` and `bucket`, that is.

Straight from the previous example, you can use code similar to what's below to retrieve the download link:

```
if res, err := service.Objects.Get(bucketName, objectName).Do(); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("The media download link for %v/%v is %v.\n\n", bucketName, res.Name, res.MediaLink)
} else {
    fatalf(service, "Failed to get %s/%s: %s.", bucketName, objectName, err)
}
```

Then, fetch the file, or do whatever you want with it. Full example:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/jwt"
    "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1"
    "fmt"
)

...

const (
    bucketName = "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
    objectName = "mythumb.jpg"
)

func main() {
    conf := &jwt.Config{
        Email: "xxx@developer.com",
        PrivateKey: []byte("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----..."),
        Subject:    "user@example.com",
        TokenURL:   "https://provider.com/o/oauth2/token",
     }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)

    service, err := storage.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        fatalf(service, "Failed to create service %v", err)
    }

    if res, err := service.Objects.Get(bucketName, objectName).Do(); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("The media download link for %v/%v is %v.\n\n", bucketName, res.Name, res.MediaLink)
    } else {
        fatalf(service, "Failed to get %s/%s: %s.", bucketName, objectName, err)
    }

    // Go fetch the file, etc.
}
```

## Third ????: "what code to encoce base64 data"?

Pretty simple with the [`encoding/base64`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/) package. SO simple, that they've included an [example](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#example_Encoding_EncodeToString):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("any + old & data")
    str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If this answers your question, consider selecting it as the answer.

Comment: The minutia of the implementation details are in the docs of the linked package repos. Likewise goes for printing it to the browser; this is a solution to your questions, not an implementation of your application.

Comment: The best I can do is link you to these two resources: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the bullets towards the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Though, in reality, you have not: "...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions."

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Still got error for the import library of **the second ????** stating: `cannot find package "golang.org/x/oauth2" in any of:
 /usr/src/go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2 (from $GOROOT)
 /go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2 (from $GOPATH)` I run the code [here](http://play.golang.org/p/caPzto97Ix)